# web api XmlMediaTypeFormatter exception

Tags: interface, inversion-of-control, asp.net-web-api, xml-formatting

I want to use IoC / the dependency resolver of the web api framework for decoupling.

The XmlFormatter cant serialize interfaces,... Ok. But what would be the purpose of IoC and the DependencyResolver if I cant return xml?

I cant even do this:
(Method in my ApiController)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<Project> projects = new List<IProject>() { new Project(), new Project() }.Select(p => p as Project);

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Project>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, projects);

            return response;
        }
```

I create a list of IProjects and cast them to 'Project'. But while creating the response I get this:

> The configured formatter
>   'System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.XmlMediaTypeFormatterTracer' cannot
>   write an object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2'.

That is a XmlMediaTypeFormatterTracer? I dont want tracing that throws errors while serialization. (BTW: I replaced the standard XMLformatter with my own one. However "XmlMediaTypeFormatterTracer" throws the exception...
Info: I get the same error while using the standard formatter)

Why is this XmlMediaTypeFormatterTracer called even if I implement my own xmlformatter?

Answer (score 4):

my problem solved with

`config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Tracing in your application? If yes, the Tracing logic wraps formatters into its a wrapper tracer formatters.